# Find a TMP_InputField and then get the text from it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, text, null

I'm having trouble finding a TextMeshPro Input Field, getting it's component and then storing the text from it in a string.  I've been able to do it before but only when I've assigned the input field publically in the inspector, eveything breaks when I try to find it privately.

It's declared like this (sorry if my terminology is wrong)-

`private TMP_InputField angleInputField;`

and then in Start-

`angleInputField = GameObject.FindWithTag("AngleInputField").GetComponent<TMP_InputField>();`

But then I get a null ref when later this is used in a function-

`angleInputString = angleInputField.text;`

I've tried finding angleInputField by name and get the same result and I've messed around with it so much I can't get it to work publically anymore!

Answer (score 1):

Why not link it in the editor? Add `[SerializeField]` before `private TMP_InputField angleInputField;` and just link it up in the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

```
TMP_InputField inputField = GameObject.Find("InputField (TMP)").GetComponent<TMP_InputField>();
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, please consider reading [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) This may help you understand why answers without an explanation are less helpful than no answer.

Kind Regards!